# how to format and position text properly in bootstrap 2 nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need some help with Bootstrap 2

How do I get "text" to position and formatted nicely in the navbar ?

http://jsfiddle.net/sGgKE/198/

```
     <div id="navbarExample" class="navbar navbar-static">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
            <a class="brand" href="#">w3resource</a>
            ...
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                  <li>Name</li>  <---- this text looks a bit weird and not positioned properly
              </ul>   
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

By the way, it should be just text, not a link. If I do like this it will work but I dont want it to be a link.

```
<li class=""><a href="">Name</a></li>
```

Comment: I'ved got my example from this http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/scrollspy-tutorial.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not actually behaves strange. The `PHP` and `DB` elements are aligned centered because they have corresponding styles in the selectrors.

`.navbar .nav>li>a{
   float:none; 
   padding: 10px 15px 10px;
   color:#777777;
   text-decoration:none;
   text-shadow:0 1px 0 #ffffff;
}`

and in the `.navbar .nav` selector.

Your `ul` element does not have those styles affected, that is why it is aligned absolutely the way it should (not vertically centered). If you want your `Name` element to be aligned vertically centered, you can try to apply `margin` to the `ul`.

Here is the worrking [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGgKE/200/) with a possible workaround.